# Snowflake SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL output query results in the email body

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have my notification integration working and I'm able to send emails via the CREATE ALERT.

What I'm struggling to work out is how to output the results of a query into the body for teh SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL proc.

I would like all rows within a daily monitoring output table included in the body to alert on the contents >> DB.LOAD_SUCCESS_TRACKING

What is the best way to do this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ALERT test
WAREHOUSE = ITSM_LWH
SCHEDULE = '1 minute'
IF (EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM DB.LOAD_SUCCESS_TRACKING))
THEN CALL SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL(
    'ITSM_EMAIL',
     'nyoung@XXXXXX.net',
     'Game Alert: Possible degraded games on GS.',
     'Email Body.'
 );

 ALTER ALERT test RESUME;
```

Thanks
NY

Comment: Im not sure this is practical even if its possible.  Firstly you'll have to capture the RESULTSET from the query then iterate over each row with a cursor concatenating all the columns together then appending it to an ever growing VARCHAR with \n as "row" seperators.  You'll soon blow the VARCHAR limit for the email body or end up with an unreadable email.
To achieve a similar result why not return the SQLID of the tracking query in the email body?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but this guy looks like he's doing what you're asking for: 
https://medium.com/snowflake/hey-snowflake-send-me-an-email-243741a0fe3

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling Send Email Function in action you can write procedure which would accept arguments which are required for Send Email Function and call that Send Email Inside Procedure. And Call This Procedure in Alert.
You can construct Body for sending email Inside Procedure.

Something Like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_SEND_EMAIL(integration_name VARCHAR,email_address_1 VARCHAR,SUBJECT VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
Body TEXT; SendEmailSQL VARCHAR;
BEGIN
-- Construct your body here
SendEmailSQL:= ' CALL SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL(:integration_name ,:email_address_1, :SUBJECT, :Body  )';--This is Dynamic SQL

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (: SendEmailSQL);
-- Try exception handling here
RETURN ' Successfully Send Email'
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, apologies I am not sure I understand how the above would allow the contents of a table from a select * query to be populated in the email body

Comment: @NRY this is not exact procedure, i specifically said in my statement that "You can construct Body for sending email Inside Procedure" and made comment in the procedure as -- Construct your body here